# R function to convert object into code

Tags: r, object

I am looking for a function in R that converts an object into code that can be used to create a replica of that object. Something like this:

```
> myObject=c(1, 2, 3)
> magicFunction(myObject)
[1] "c(1,2,3)"
```

I think this function exists, but I cannot find it. Would greatly appreciate your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can use `deparse`

```
deparse(myObject)
#[1] "c(1, 2, 3)"
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also use `dput`, as this retains the structure of the object as opposed to a character string representation of it.

From `?dput`:

> Writes an ASCII text representation of an R object to a file or connection, or uses one to recreate the object.

For example

```
myObject=c(1, 2, 3)

dput(myObject)
# c(1, 2, 3)


identical(myObject, dput(myObject))
# c(1, 2, 3)
# [1] TRUE

## whereas
identical(myObject, deparse(myObject))
# [1] FALSE
```